# Why is this set determined to be empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Eccles' *Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning*, problem 7.1 asks you to determine the set for:

$${\{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, m \leq n \}}$$

The answer provided in the back of the book is $\emptyset$. Why is $\{1\}$ not an answer? It satisfies $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $m \leq n$, does it not?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}^+$ the set of positive integers or the set of nonnegative integers?

Comment: Ask yourself, can you name an integer $n$ such that it is bigger than or equal to every positive integer? If you have such an $n$ then that becomes a member of your set. But if you cannot find any $n$, then the set must be empty.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but for a different question. -- $\{\,n\in\Bbb Z^+\mid \forall m\in\Bbb Z^+, n\le m\,\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is $1\geq m$ for every positive integer $m$? In words, the set is the set of all positive integers greater than or equal to all positive integers.

Comment: Ah I see, I had forgotten about the $\forall$ "for all" qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, **m** is an arbitrary integer. You are going to pick an integer **n** which satisfying the condition **for all m belongs to Z, m <=n**.
If you are choosing n=1 then it fails for m=2.
So we come to know that there is no such integer **n**.
Thus the set having no elements.
**Empty set.**

Answer (score 0):

$$\{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}^+, m \leq n \}$$

To say that $1$ is a member of this set means that the statement $\forall m\in\mathbb Z^+, m \le n$ is true when $1$ is put in the role of $n$. The expression $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ identifies $n$ as the variables in whose place $1$ must appear. Thus you'd be saying
$$
\forall m \in \mathbb Z^+, m \le 1.
$$
Thus every member of $\mathbb Z^+$ would be $\le 1.$

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that the statement below holds:
\begin{align}
&\exists x(x\in\Bbb Z^+\land\forall y(y\in\Bbb Z^+\to y\le x))\\
&\alpha\in\Bbb Z^+\land\forall y(y\in\Bbb Z^+\to y\le \alpha)&&\text{so there is an $\alpha$ satisfing the statement}\\
&\forall y(y\in\Bbb Z^+\to y\le \alpha) && \text{pick $y\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\alpha <y$}\\
&y\le\alpha\land\alpha<y\\
&y<y && \text{but '<' relation isn't reflexive, i.e. $\forall x\neg(a<a)$}\\
&\bot
\end{align}
It shows that our initial assumption was wrong and there is no such element exists.